# iPad's Safari does not remember server proxy configuration

Tags: proxy, squid, ipad, safari

I block all direct internet traffic of my company's network.

Everybody now must use a proxy, but in all iPads, I can not solve this trouble:

iPad works, but can not save proxy authentication then for every http session of Safari it asks for proxy authentication EVERY time.

The proxy is Squid 2.7

Answer (score 2):

In the intervening 3.5 years since this question was asked, I presume you found an answer.

But if you didn't, this is what I do on my iPad and iPhone (screenshots from my iPhone since it's what I had handy as I sat in the airport).

## Go to Settings, Wi-Fi

[image]

## Then tap the (i) button on the appropriate SSID

[image]

## Scroll down and turn on <kbd>Manual</kbd> under `HTTP PROXY`, where you can enter server specifics

[image]

Every time I do this, I have no issues.